# Is this sleep command in my tmux script a justified hack? If so why?

Tags: python, linux, bash, tmux

#### NOTE

I am not sure if this question is relevant here or on **Meta** but please go through the post before a downvote!

---

I think the question looks a bit vague but I will dwell into this question extensively.

I am working with a decent number of **Raspberry Pis**. The specifications are as follows:

- **Raspbian Wheezy 7.10/7.11**
- **Model-B Raspberry Pi - 2**

As a method for running scripts in a detachable mode I am using `tmux` on the Pis.

I created a bash script to start a tmux session which gets triggered on boot of the Pi using the `crontab` and `@reboot` tag. In a nutshell:

```
 # have a bash script to trigger the session on boot
 # in a bin/ folder in $HOME directory
 /home/pi/bin/session.sh
 
 # above mentioned path gets triggered on crontab reboot

 ## In the crontab
 @reboot /home/pi/bin/session.sh
```

How does the `session.sh` look like?

```
 #!/bin/bash

 tmux new-session -d -s session1

 tmux set-option -t session1 set-remain-on-exit-on

 tmux new-window -d -n 'pyScript' -t session1:1 'sudo /home/pi/bin/pyScript.py'

 exit 0
```

As mentioned before the `pyScript.py` has `socket` application on it. So we open a socket and send and receive data on the Pi based on an application.

#### Initial Observations

- Upon reboot of the Pi the python Script failed. This was checked when we attach the `tmux` session using `tmux a`. An error on the Python script makes the `tmux window` freeze which shows **Pane is Dead**. The reason `pyScript.py` failed was that the socket did not `bind`.

Initially I thought it was a programming fault on my side but if I run the script by myself like `sudo /home/pi/bin/myScript.py` the script runs *flawlessly*! **No errors or exceptions are caught**.

> It is exactly the same script.

- I tried all changes in the script to overcome any **Binding Errors** from the python script, but everytime I reboot the script with would trigger an error with the same binding Error

What is the error I always catch?

> setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, mreq)
>
> device not found

This was really funny because all the network interfaces are set up and running before crontab script is triggered and the tmux session is created.

### Inference aka. Hack

I had a bout with `tmux` before and some of the scripts I used to get triggered also used to fail before. Hence the *Hack* that I introduced is a `sleep` command. So now my `session.sh` script looks something like :

```
## see the magic sleep here! Script works great now!
tmux new-window -d -n 'pyScript' -t session1:1 'sleep 20; sudo /home/pi/bin/pyScript.py'
```

> Now the script triggers perfectly! Everything is just the way I want it!

### Question Through Inference

Since `tmux` is based on **C** and it is a compiler based language and since my script is **Python** and it is a interpreter based language:

> Is this inherent to C being faster than Python and the Py Interpreter needs some time to *set everything up!* and hence the justification of the `sleep`?

I am not a **Computer Scientist / Engineer** but I would like a plausible explanation for the Hack of adding a `sleep` command.

I realize that C/C++ are really *fast* compared to Interpreter based languages like Python.Is this the clear application that shows how these two languages vary?

Just a Curious mind trying to figure and justify my work !!

THANKS

### Reference

I found [This Thread: Crontab SQL boot crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805490/raspberry-pi-crontab-starts-py-script-at-bootup-logging-error-mysql-2002-ca) Which resolves the problem Exactly with my Hack idea.

Comment: I don't consider it to be a hack by using _sleep_, as it's available for good reasons. You're making way to big a deal over nothing. If sleeping the process is what it takes... then it's what it takes. :)

Comment: No no ! Please don't get me wrong I spent an insane day just to get this thing working. And you are right but this case also gave me in-depth perspective of the Raspbian/ Debian environment and its functionalities. plus I got immense reps ;) for things I figured out for it on Super User and RPi Stack sites.

Answer (score 2):

Crontab runs `@reboot` scripts **before** the system is finished rebooting.  If your script needs services that are not available until the reboot is complete, your script needs to either (a) test for the presence of those services before using them, or (b) don't use `@reboot`.

If you need all the services to be available, consider using instead `/etc/rc.local`.  On most systems (FreeBSD excepted), it runs [after reboot is complete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49635/53604).

#### Documentation

From `man 5 crontab`:

> Please  note  that  startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, is the
>   time when the cron(8) daemon startup.  **In particular, it may be before
>   some system daemons, or other facilities, were startup.**  This is due
>   to the boot order sequence of the machine.  [Emphasis added.]

Information on editing `rc.local` for the Raspberry Pi is [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md).

#### More on `rc.local` and boot order

On a Debian-like system, the file `/etc/init.d/rc.local` normally includes the header:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rc.local
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Run /etc/rc.local if it exist
### END INIT INFO
```

The line `# Required-Start:    $all` indicates that this script should be run only after *all* other services have started.

One can verify how the system interprets the `$all` string in that line by checking `/etc/init.d/.depend.start`.  It should contain a line for `rc.local` like:

```
rc.local: rsyslog dbus atd cups-browsed avahi-daemon smartmontools cups bootlogs motd acpid ntp rsync ssh cron
```

This line explicitly lists all the services that should be running before `rc.local` starts.

The file `/etc/init.d/.depend.start` is managed by the system.

Comment: Hi  I actually tried the same script triggering with `rc.local` and still got the same errors! This makes sense since `rc.local` gets triggered before the cron daemon. What would you suggest? what about a `init.d/` daemon script?

Comment: @Shan-Desai Well, that is disappointing!  I am using rc.local on Debian (which Raspian is based on) systems, both Jessie and Stretch, and it seems to safely run _after_ boot.

Comment: you have no idea I was searching for an answer for 4 months. I spent 8 hours at a stretch to figure out how to trigger the script.  Incidentally I figured out the solution when I ran the complete logic on my Ubuntu laptop and assuming that Raspbian is based on Debian I tried it out on the Pi. I agree that the logic world perfectly on my laptop but the pi will fail at getting the sockets ready somehow. Thanks though

Comment: @Shan-Desai Does your Pi have the file `/etc/init.d/.depend.start`?  If so, what is listed in it under `rc.local`?

Comment: Will have look at it tomorrow and update you. Unfortunately not at work today

Comment: @Shan-Desai Very good.  While you are there, have a look at the order (alphanumeric sorting) of the files in `/etc/rc3.d`.  The `/etc/rc3.d/S*rc.local` file should be at or near the end.